# Counting number of occurrences recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why is this recursive countOccurence function not working? this has a subroutine. is there a way to do it without a subroutine? it seems in javascript you have to have a closure (subroutine function) for the counter variable, otherwise it gets rewritten every time!

```
function numOccurencesRecursive(arr, val) {
  //base case. check it if it only has a length of 1
  var count = 0;

  function doCount(arr, val) {
    if (arr[0] === val) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count += doCount(arr.slice(1), val)
    }
    return count;
  }

  return doCount(arr, val);
}

console.log(numOccurencesRecursive([2, 7, 4, 4, 1, 4], 4)); // should return 3 but returns 1
```

Comment: *Remove* the outer `count` variable and handle the base case by `return 0`; then add in a proper recurrence case. You have all the counting information needed for 'is this character a match?' and 'how many of the next characters match?' for a recurrence case. That will simplify the logic - including fixing this bug - and make it closer to an 'ideal' recursive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you were thinking iteratively but used a recursive approach.

The iterative approach has a global variable which may be updated at each step:

```js
function numOccurencesIterative(arr, val) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) if(arr[i] === val) ++count;
  return count;
}
```

However, when using recursive approaches, better avoid global variables.

```js
function numOccurencesRecursive(arr, val) {
  if(!arr.length) return 0;
  return (arr[0] === val) + numOccurencesRecursive(arr.slice(1), val);
}
```

Comment: Whoa, cool... how are you adding a recursive call to a boolean, and then getting a number? Could you show the first few recursive calls?

Comment: @freezycold The boolean is converted to the number `0` or `1` under the hood. You may prefer `(arr[0] === val ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Awesome. how could I refactor to return me the first element that occurs an even number of times? Going to edit code above to include my attempt at that

Comment: I would use a map (or object if all items are uniquely identified by strings) to count how many times each item appears in the array. And then iterate those until even. `var m = new Map(); arr.forEach(item => m.set(item, (m.get(item) || 0) + 1)); arr.find(item => !(m.get(item) % 2))`

Comment: Thanks. here's a shoutout to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304235/refactoring-working-recursion-code-hasfivedivs-for-traversing-the-dom

Comment: Is this tail recursion?

Answer (score 4):

This should definitely do with all the nests with recursion:

```
function countItems(arr, item) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (typeof(arr[i]) == typeof([])){
            count += countItems(arr[i], item);
        }
        else{
            if(typeof(arr[i]) != typeof([])){
                if (arr[i] === item){
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`doCount` stops recursing once it finds a match; hence, it will never find more than 1 match to count.

Comment: I'm not seeing that, could you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

So, what you are doing is that you are incrementing the count only when you find the value, and when you do find it, your recursive function ends, but its the other way around, which means you have to count for unfound elements in the array and if you find something, increment it and then if the array is empty, return the count.

Code:

```
function numOccurencesRecursive(arr, val) {
//base case. check it if it only has a length of 1
var count = 0;

function doCount(arr, val) {
    if (arr[0] === val) {
        count++;
    } else if (!arr.length) {
        return count;
    }
    return doCount(arr.slice(1), val);
}

return doCount(arr, val);
}

console.log(numOccurencesRecursive([2, 7, 4, 4, 1, 4], 4)); // should return 3 but returns 1
```

Comment: I didn't quite understood what the function should have done at first, i've fixed it :) now should work.

Comment: This will produce an infinite recursion if `val === undefined`. I recommend checking `arr.length` before `arr[0] === val`.