# refactoring working recursion code (hasFiveDIVs) for traversing the DOM

Tags: javascript, recursion, refactoring

@oriol provided an amazing two line recursive solution for a problem I was working on today.

```
function numOccurencesRecursive(arr, val) {
  if (!arr.length) return 0;
  return (arr[0] === val ? 1 : 0) + numOccurencesRecursive(arr.slice(1), val);
}
```

I was inspired to refactor some spagetti-ish code that I wrote yesterday:

```
//returns a boolean
    function containsFiveOrMoreDivs(domElement) {
      var count = 0;

  function doCount(domElement) {
    if (domElement && domElement.tagName === "DIV") {
      count++;
    }

    if (count >= 5) {
      return true;
    }

    if (domElement.hasChildNodes()) {
      var children = domElement.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (doCount(children[i])) {
          return true
        }
      };
    };

    return false;
  }

  return doCount(domElement)
}
containsFiveOrMoreDivs(document);
```

Here's the attempt:

```
function containsFiveOrMoreDivsPureRecursion(domElement) {
  if (!domElement && domElement.tagName !== "DIV") {
    return 0;
  }
  return (domElement.tagName === "DIV" ? 1 : 0) + containsFiveOrMoreDivsPureRecursion(domElement.childNodes()); //?
}
```

how would I loop through all the child nodes recursively in this version? Is what I'm doing possible?

Comment: The name of the functions implies a boolean return value and not the number of divs found in `domElement` (incl. `domElement` what is not obvious regarding the function name). A non-recursive solution is not an option? `var divs = (domElement.tagName === "DIV" ? 1 : 0) + domElement.querySelectorAll("div").length`

Comment: thanks @Andreas. So I would save that variable outside the if, and then return that? This is an exercise to better understand recursion, so can you show me what you were thinking in terms of recursion? I wasn't clear if you are saying to do it with recursion or not.

Comment: If it's an exercise then ignore my non-recursion-example :) Have a look at [`walkTheDOM`](http://www.javascriptcookbook.com/article/Traversing-DOM-subtrees-with-a-recursive-walk-the-DOM-function/) from Douglas Crockford. You will have to adjust some steps but the recursion part won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With recursion, you should remember to return 1 type of value, however you want to return a boolean yet you want your function to return count too.  This really complicates things.

Heres a recursive function to count the element types

```
function countElements(domElement, elementType) {
    count = (domElement && domElement.tagName === elementType.toUpperCase());

    if (domElement.hasChildNodes()) {
      for (var i = 0; i < domElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
        count += countElements(domElement.childNodes[i], elementType); 
      };
    };

    return count;
}
```

you can use it like this to achieve what you want.

```
countElements(document, 'div') >= 5
```

However, this might not be the most efficient way of doing it since it will traverse the whole DOM tree but what you really want is for it to stop when you've hit 5 elements.

```
function containsFiveOrMoreDivsPureRecursion(domElement, elementType) {
    var count = 0;

    function countElements(domElement, elementType) {
        count += (domElement && domElement.tagName === elementType.toUpperCase());

        if (count >= 5) return count;

        if (domElement.hasChildNodes()) {
          for (var i = 0; i < domElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
            countElements(domElement.childNodes[i], elementType); 
          };
        };

        return count;
    }


    return countElements(domElement, elementType) >= 5;
}
```

In this example, you will need to keep a variable outside of your function (thus it's not really a pure recursion) to keep track of the count and be able to return a boolean.